# Capture Posted Data from other website to AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to prepare secure application in AngularJs, which handle payment related common website(means we can get request from multiple website for payment in secure website).

Now issue I am facing.

When ever we are sending data from one of the website in post form to our Angularjs secure application we are unable to capture those posted form data.
Example:- www.xyz.com is the website from we capturing some data of users in post form and then sending to our AngularJs secure application(secure.xyz.com/app/index.html#lmnpage) for further processing. Now my problem comes up here, how to capture http://www.xyz.com data to https://secure.xyz.com/app/index.html#lmnpage for further processing.

Help me out from this situation as I am new in AngularJs.

Answer (score 0):

Due to [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_Site_Scripting) issues; you cannot post data from one domain to another.

You may consider trying [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) on the Angular [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) object.  It is, essentially, a get call.

[CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) may also be an option, but I have not used that myself.

If you need something more advanced, you could in theory use a SWF that communicates with the UI via the JavaScript bridge and then cal call your server if you put a crossdomain.xml file into place on your server.  This would, of course, present cross platform issues on browsers were Flash is not supported (such as mobile devices).

[Note: I have no idea how compatible any of these ideas are with PCI Compliance standards]